# How to hide program file directory in php desktop software

Tags: php, inno-setup, phpdesktop

So, I'm writing a program for a company. But they don't want a web based project and I wrote all the codes in php. So I used php desktop and inno compiler to build a simple desktop software. My problem is when I compile the files in to a setup file and install it on another computer, it shows all the main files in the folder directory leaving my codes prone to editing. I just want to know if there is a way to make the files hidden or something so that the  user cannot see it. I've tried asking this question on other platforms but couldn't find an answer. Please I need help.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like this: http://www.zzee.com/phpexe

Comment: In phpdesktop PHP sources can be protected with many of the available PHP encoders, see: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#how-do-i-protect-php-sources-in-the-www-directory